# Are all same type fiber optic transceiver compatible?

Tags: fiber, layer1, transceiver

Can I order a 1000BASE-LX transceiver from any source and it will be compatible with all others 1000BASE-LX ?

Would a link with a Juniper 1000BASE-LX and a TrendNet 1000BASE-LX transceiver work?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

1000BASE-LX is a standard the same way 1000BASE-T is. You expect any copper interfaces with 1000BASE-T to interoperate, and you should expect the same thing with fiber 1000BASE-LX interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

While this is true on the fiber side of the system, and SHOULD be true on the thing with the transceiver socket (SFP, typically, for current Gigabit stuff) it is evidently not always true for certain annoying manufacturers that like to lock you into their house-brand transceivers at far above the cost of standard/generic/standards-compliant transceivers.

One of many reasons I avoid certain brands by default.

Comment: I think you are answering a different question. The question is about linking two different vendor's transceivers, not using one vendor's in another vendor's equipment. You are correct on that point.

Comment: Well, I don't know who's box the Trendnet SFP is going into, and thought the *possibility* of a "brand" problem on the electrical side of the interface should at least be on the radar. I assume the Juniper interface is in a Juniper box.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to connect one SMode transceiver with a MMode transceiver, you will get your link UP, because they are standars of the market, and only can be negative the transmision distance from one to other, or wavelength mistmatch(850, 1310 or 1550 nm) . Here, on Wikipedia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet, you can find the transmission distance of each one.

In other words, if you are on the working range, all the tranceiver will work normally.

Comment: Actually, range (or better: signal strength) is just one of the relevants components here. The actual wavelength of light transmitted by the optics is just as relevant.

Comment: And 1000-BaseLX incorporates both those things, so it's not loosey-goosey - it's specified. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-LX